# No se puede hacer scroll dentro de un textfield multiline

Tags: flutter

tengo un problema al que actualmente no encuentro solucion y lo que pasa es que al intentar hacer scroll cuando el `TextField` llega al final no deja o llega al top no deja hacer scroll al resto del Widget para poder hacerlo tengo que buscar un peque;o borde por fuera del `TextField` para poder hacer el scroll hacia alguna direccion.

Tendran alguna idea de que estoy aplicando mal?

Ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Codigo:

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: [
      const SelectedAccountBarWidget(), <--- Widget que siempre se debe mantener top.
      Expanded(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(EdgeInsetsSize().defaultSize),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              DropdownButtonFormField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(label: Text("Type")),
                value: null,
                items: const [],
                onChanged: (value) {},
              ),
              const TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(label: Text("Subject")),
              ),
              const TextField(
                keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.top,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  label: Text("Message"),
                ),
                minLines: 5,
                maxLines: 20,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      )
    ]);
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Tienes un scroll dentro de un scroll. Textfield es naturalmente un scroll, y está dentro de SingleChildScrollView. Esto está causando el comportamiento conflictivo. Elimine SingleChildScrollView y agregue resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false al scaffold para evitar un desbordamiento abajo.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
    resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text(widget.title),
    ),
    body: Center(
        child: Column(children: [
      Expanded(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            DropdownButtonFormField(
              decoration: const InputDecoration(label: Text("Type")),
              value: null,
              items: const [],
              onChanged: (value) {},
            ),
            const TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(label: Text("Subject")),
            ),
            const TextField(
              keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
              textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
              textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.top,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                label: Text("Message"),
              ),
              minLines: 5,
              maxLines: 20,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ])));
```

}

Comment: Esta respuesta no soluciona el problema. Si quita el SingleChildScrollView, no va a poder ver todos los formularios, si la pantalla es demasiado pequeña para mostrarlo.

Comment: La sugerencia de @Scott no fue la solucion definitiva pero si me ayudo a;adiendo `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true` a lo que ya tenia aplicado soluciona el problema, gracias.